# jquery ajax encoding problem

Tags: post, jquery, encode

I have this script

```
var htm = function (){return $('#home_page_frame').html().trim()};

var data = {
   type: "POST",
   url: "save_changes.php",
   data:  "par="+ htm(),
   success: function(msg){
     alert('OK')
   }
 };
$.ajax(data);
```

Save_changes.php

```
echo $_POST;
```

The problem is that if `htm()` is `=` to `'Save & Exit'` or `'Save &amp; Exit'`
it returns only the `Save` and (i think it may be using the & as a new post parameter

I have tried encoding decoding, it's doing my heading SOS pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let jQuery encode the data by passing in an object, like this:

```
data: { par: htm() },
```

This way that `&` gets encoded to a `%26` like this: `Save%20%26%20Exit`.  What using an oject is really doing under the covers is calling [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), like this:

```
data:  "par="+encodeURIComponent(htm())
```

Comment: I wish I could of asked earlier and saved myself a headache and a couple hours :) thnx